# GridView + Access Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to link Access database with GridView control.

Here's the question:
One successful procedure to link database query.

```
Protected sub  Query(ByVal y as string)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(y, cn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    da.Dispose()
    cn.Dispose()
    Me.GridView1.DataSource = dt
    Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    ListBox1.Visible = True
End sub
```

What I wanted is to re-run query if the first run returns no value/result in another procedure.

```
Protected Sub btnFind_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click    

x = "SELECT * From Class Where Gender ='Male' And First_name ='James' "
        Query(x)    
If gridview.rows.count =0 then
x= "SELECT * From Class Where Gender ='Male'"
       query(x)
    End If
```

then put result into listbox.

However, I got error of `"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." on da.Fill(dt)` when running the second time. First time was successful.

OK I finally got mistake corrected. I gotta  Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source = C:\Class.mdb") again to use query instead of once for all queries.

Comment: You need to show us more of your code - the problem is related to where you call `Query()`. It may be easier to modify your actual query so that it will integrate your two current queries and always return a result.

Comment: If you dispose the connection, that's the minimum error you could expect.

Answer (score 1):

Create and dispose the connection in the same method

```
Protected Sub Query(ByVal y as string)     
  Dim dt As New DataTable()
  Using cn as New OleDbConnection("your_connection_string"), _
        da As New OleDbDataAdapter(y, cn)       
      da.Fill(dt)     
  End Using
  Me.GridView1.DataSource = dt     
  Me.GridView1.DataBind()     
End Sub
```

Comment: OK I finally got mistake corrected. I gotta Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source = C:\Class.mdb") again to use query instead of once for all queries.

Comment: Well, if you follow my answer this will never happens

Comment: Current snippet doesn't compile.  You need to add another `End Using` or remove the second `Using` keyword and add a `, _` to the first Using statement.

Comment: @LarsTech oh yes, used :-) to be on C#

Comment: Oh, well, I like this site, I never stop to learn something new, Thanks again @LarsTech

Comment: I must be having a slow morning.  Had to fix my fix.

Comment: Instead, we had a very eventful morning here in Italy. I'm still keeping an eye on the ceiling lamps.